# Unwanted Special Characters added to Android Save File

Tags: android, file-io, nullpointerexception, special-characters

I think I have a rough idea what the problem is, but not entirely sure. Had a search for a similar solution but only answers for C.

I am writing a list of string values to an `internal storage file`.

```
        OUTSTREAM = saveName.toString() + "," +
                d3S.getText().toString() + "," + d3M.getText().toString() + "," + d3C.isChecked() + "," +
                d4S.getText().toString() + "," + d4M.getText().toString() + "," + d4C.isChecked() + "," +
                d6S.getText().toString() + "," + d6M.getText().toString() + "," + d6C.isChecked() + "," +
                d8S.getText().toString() + "," + d8M.getText().toString() + "," + d8C.isChecked() + "," +
                d10S.getText().toString() + "," + d10M.getText().toString() + "," + d10C.isChecked() + "," +
                d12S.getText().toString() + "," + d12M.getText().toString() + "," + d12C.isChecked() + "," +
                d20S.getText().toString() + "," + d20M.getText().toString() + "," + d20C.isChecked() + "," +
                d100S.getText().toString() + "," + d100M.getText().toString() + "," + d100C.isChecked() + "," +
                dCustS.getText().toString() + "," + dCustND.getText().toString() + "," + dCustM.getText().toString() + "," + dCustC.isChecked();

    Log.d("OUTSTREAM::", "" + OUTSTREAM + ";");
    Log.d("OUTSTREAM Bytes::", "" + OUTSTREAM.getBytes() + ";");

        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND); //MODE_APPEND MODE_PRIVATE
            fos.write(OUTSTREAM.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Save FileNotFoundException",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Save IOException",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

LogCat:

```
08-13 11:33:12.486: D/OUTSTREAM::(1547): NewSave,1,0,true,1,0,true,1,0,true,1,0,true,1,0,true,1,0,true,1,0,true,1,0,true,1,5,0,true;
08-13 11:33:12.486: D/OUTSTREAM Bytes::(1547): [B@52a6507c;
```

But when I write to file, my data gets additional special characters added to the end of the file.

```
        try{
         fIn = openFileInput("DiceSaves.txt");
         isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
         isr.read(inputBuffer);
         data = new String(inputBuffer);
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loaded: " + data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


         List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(data.split("\n"));
         Object[] aLinesArray = lines.toArray();

         String[] SaveNames = new String[10];
         int n = 0;

         for(int i = 0; i < aLinesArray.length ; i++){
             String line = aLinesArray[i].toString();
             Log.d("i and Line::", "" + i + "," + line + ";");
```

LogCat:

```
08-13 11:35:08.766: D/i and Line::(1547): 0,NewSave,1,0,true,1,0,true,1,0,true,1,0,true,1,0,true,1,0,true,1,0,true,1,0,true,1,5,0,true??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????;
```

I wasn't sure if I needed to add `"\n", "\r\n"` or leave it without, as I am `appending` to the file. If I don't need either the new line then I need to `null` the end of the file from the last enrty with `"\0"` or something...

This was built on a fresh Geny Mototion AVD with SGS4 4.4.2 each execution, to ensure the file is freshly made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unwanted characters aren't being added to the file, the problem is in the way you read the data back in. You're not using the length returned by `isr.read(inputBuffer)`.

All you need to do is change

```
isr.read(inputBuffer);
data = new String(inputBuffer);
```

to

```
int length = isr.read(inputBuffer);
data = new String(inputBuffer, 0, length);
```

It doesn't break anything, but I'm also not sure why you convert your string array to a list and then back to an array here:

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(data.split("\n"));
Object[] aLinesArray = lines.toArray();
```

You could just do:

```
String[] aLinesArray = data.split("\n");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, you've helped tremendously.
Yeah not sure either, now that you mention it...